# React app with typescript I want to integrate SSR in my app But got error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm using ReactDOMServer to render an app, and I got the following error:

[image]

I've setup express in react typescript project. What am I doing wrong? Please help me out, thanks you.

Here's the relevant code:

**App.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Testing App Page</h1>
    );

  }
}

export default App
```

**entry.js**

```
require('ignore-styles');

require("@babel/register")({

    ignore: [ /(node_modules)/ ],
    presets: [[
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "esmodules": true
        }
      }
    ], '@babel/preset-react']
});

require('./index');
```

**index.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import serverRenderer from './middleware/renderer';

const PORT = 3000;
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
router.use('^/$', serverRenderer);

// other static resources should just be served as they are
router.use(express.static(
    path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build'),
    { maxAge: '1d' },
));
app.use(router);
app.listen(PORT, (error) => {
    console.log("App port listen on ", PORT);
});
```

**middleware/renderer.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'


import App from '../../src/App';
// const App = require("../../src/App"); <= also try this but not work

const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

export default (req, res, next) => {

    // point to the html file created by CRA's build tool
    const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'build', 'index.html');

    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, htmlData) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('err', err);
            return res.status(404).end()
        }

        // render the app as a string
        const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(<App />));

        // inject the rendered app into our html and send it
        return res.send(
            htmlData.replace(
                '<div id="root"></div>',
                `<div id="root">${html}</div>`
            )
        );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to typescript. In `middleware/renderer.js` you wrote:

```
const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(<App />));
```

This is incorrect. Change it to:

```
const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(App));
```

And you're good to go.

You should read the error message. It's already told you what is going wrong. Also learn more about the React concepts, especially the difference between "JSX Element" and "JSX Component".

Comment: Then you're not showing us the relevant error message. "Not work" is pointless, tell us how does it not work?

Comment: I tried your solution but I got this error
```React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.  ```
If I write directly **App** in html data, It's worked but routing not working.
`return res.send(
            htmlData.replace(
                '<div id="root"></div>',
                `<div id="root">${App}</div>`
            )
        );`

Comment: If I write directly **App** It's work.
For routing need any configuration ?